# Missing dSYMs in 1 version in the last 24 hrs Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash, google-fabric

We are adding pod file for fabric and Crashlytics in our project. When I tried to place a crash in my Crashlytics. I am getting this “Missing dSYMs in 1 version in the last 24 hrs ”error. But my previous version of my app getting an error in the crash dashboard. my latest build not getting an error in the dashboard. We have tried to upload dSYMs file in **window-> organiser - > show in finder - > show package content- > dSYMs file**. we zip it and upload it fabric organization in fabric.io. But crashes are not available. How to fix this issue? I want to place a crash for development scheme now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. Go to the Build Settings -> Debug Information Format -> and select DWARF with dsym file for both Debug and Release.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Leave it as default. Don't change anything.